# Cannot build codeobe integration sample

Tags: java, continuous-integration, microservices

I tried to build my own integration project by following codeobe sample found in [this](https://github.com/ObageCode/ABCHR/archive/refs/heads/main.zip) repo. However my build fails with following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project fingerprint_service: Could not
> resolve dependencies for project
> org.daniel.integration:pizza_service:jar:1.0.0: Could not find artifact
> org.codeobe.integration:codeobe-java-sdk:jar:1.0.0 in central
> (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]

Can someone please help, Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include the relevant Maven configuration. Based on your error the problem is simple: you're trying to include an external library that does not exist in the central Maven repository

Answer (score 1):

The Codeobe FAQ says this:

### How to install codeobe sdk

Download SDK from our website and use following command to install locally

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=codeobe_sdk-1.0.0.jar  \
    -DgroupId=org.susi.integration -DartifactId=codeobe_sdk 
    -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Try it.  If it doesn't work, reach out to the Codeobe team for clearer instructions on what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I am from team [Codeobe](https://www.codeobe.cloud/) & [Stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139985/stephen-c) is correct. Although we have a slight change.

Please use the command as follows.

```
$ mvn install:install-file -Dfile=codeobe-java-sdk.jar -DgroupId=org.codeobe.integration -DartifactId=codeobe-java-sdk -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

You can follow our official documentation for SDK using this [link](https://www.codeobe.cloud/docs/using-codeobe-sdk/).

If you need more help please feel free to ask it here.

Thanks